# My lamp turns on when while plugged into the receptacle when I turn on the ceiling fan on

Tags: electrical

I put on all brand new receptacles and a switch for my ceiling fan and my lamp is plugged into one of the outlets and when I turn on the fan my lamp turns on so saying how did I wire this wrong

Comment: Did it do this before?  You only replaced switch and receptacles or did you add new wire/cable.  If no ceiling light, then usually at least one receptacle is wired to a switch to have a plugged in lamp(helps if the lamp switch is left on) work to light the room by the switch.

Comment: Pictures of all the devices (outlets, switches, lights/fans, etc) you wired up, as well as a diagram showing their electrical relationship to each other (as best you understand it) would help immensely.

Comment: Is the switch that works the fan next to the entry door by chance?

Comment: If the receptacle used to work when you installed the new one did you remember to break the tab on the hot side of the receptacle?